# How to find the WAN ip for a connected computer

Tags: web-services, networking, connection, ip, wan

**I have been trying to get the IP of a person on my network, so I tried pinging them and  finding their ip on my network site, but it didn't give me their WAN ip. Please help.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the client is in your network you will probably stay in your LAN - therefore you will get the response from the private IP of course.
the WAN IP is only used when the client tries to access some IP on a public range.

one option is to ask the client to visit something like http://www.whatismyip.com/ and tell you the output or host a service yourself that is doing something similar.